# apache2 redirect from subleveldomain to URL

Tags: apache2, redirection

I need to redirect myservice.example.com to [www.example.com/myservice](http://www.example.com/myservice)

My try so far: adding a new config to apache2, doing a2ensite and restarting apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *.80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ServerAdmin administrator@example.com
 ServerName myservice.example.com
 RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com/myservice
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.443>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 ServerAdmin administrator@example.com
 ServerName myservice.example.com
 RedirectPermanent / https://www.example.com/myservice
</VirtualHost>
```

but when i enter myservice.example.com apache2 serves me [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), not [www.example.com/myservice](http://www.example.com/myservice)

What am I missing?

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect configuration is correct.

However, you need to replace the period between the IP and port in the `VirtualHost` directive with a colon.

e.g. `<VirtualHost *:80>` and `<VirtualHost *:443>`

Comment: thank you. Damn typos.